# Can mypy track string literals?

Tags: python, mypy

Is there anyway to make this work

```
from typing import Literal
def foo(bar: Literal["bar"]) -> Literal["foo"]:
    foo = "foo"
    return foo


bar = "bar"
foo(bar)
```

Here are the errors

```
foo.py:4: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "Literal['foo']")
foo.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Literal['bar']"
```

Is pretty obvious that `foo` variable and `bar` are literals because they are assigned to literals, so this is safe, but mypy seems to not track this. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't know much about Python typing, but once assigned to a variable, I think it's not a literal anymore; it's a `str` object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MyPy infers literals to their builtin type, not a `Literal` of their value.

> #### mypy [Docs » Literal types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#declaring-literal-variables)
>
> You must explicitly add an annotation to a variable to declare that it has a literal type. [..] variables without this annotation are not assumed to be literals.

To allow inference of `Literal` values, annotate the variable as `Final`:

```py
from typing import Final

from typing_extensions import Final

bar: Final = "bar"
reveal_type(bar)  # Revealed type is 'Literal['bar']?'
```

Annotating a variable as `Final` indicates that its value will not be substituted for a value of similar type. This makes it correct to infer the type as the specific `Literal` value, instead of just the general type.

Note that this inference is contextual: The type is inferred as `Literal` for all cases where a `Literal` is expected. For cases in which a type is expected, be it the literal type, a base type or TypeVar, the type is inferred as the general type.

```
reveal_type([bar])  # Revealed type is 'builtins.list[builtins.str*]'
```

Comment: Is it possible to use something similar to get mypy to interpret a list literal, say `["a", "b"]`, as `list[Literal["a", "b"]]` instead of `list[str]`?

Comment: @BallpointBen you can use `list[Literal['a', 'b']]` to get a revealed type of `builtins.list[Union[Literal['a'], Literal['b']]]`, but if the positions are important you should use `tuple[Literal['a'], Literal['b']]`

Comment: Wow, this is really crappy... It makes Literal types really annoying to work with. It looks like Pyright already does this perfectly. I wonder if mypy has a principled stance against this, or if it's just a technical limitation for now.